# md5 encrypt cookiedata with serialized array

Tags: php, cookies, encryption

I was attempting to 
encrypt de cookie data with md5, but I can not validate the hash back.

It has got to do, with the fact that **cookie_data is a serialized array**, because normal stringvalues work ok.

It's actually from a codeigniter class, but it does not work??
Does anyone know what the problem might be?

```
$hash    = substr($session, strlen($session)-32); 
$session= substr($session, 0, strlen($session)-32); 

if ($hash !==  md5($session.$this->encrypt_key))
{........
```

and the cookie value is encrypted like this

```
$cookie_data = $cookie_data.md5($cookie_data.$this->encrypt_key);
```

**EDIT**
I found that the answer is to use **urlencode en urldecode** in the proces of creating and validate
md5 hashes, because setcookie does urlencode automaticly, and thereby possibly changing the hash.

thanks, Richard

Comment: You may want to try HMAC for message authentication.

Comment: update title of question

Comment: hmac? I will look that up. But is there something I can do to make this work again?

Comment: Why do you store the session data in a cookie anyway?

Comment: It's part of a authentication library I found on codeigniter, it can also store it in a db. Wich is the saferway to go, if you are on a shared host I believe. Although, It's problably not neccasary for sessions.It could come in handy for other purposes like autologin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

md5 is a oneway function. It is not a reversible one, so you can't decrypt the data.

The only thing you can do is encrypt the original data (if you saved it elsewhere) and check  the result of this second computation.

If the value retrieved and the new value calculated are the same, the hash you received is valid (As you are doing in your code).

**EDIT**

You know, with just three lines of code I will guess some possible causes:

1. $session doesn't contains at the beginning of your code the same value of cookie_data.
2. you are using multibyte strings and strlen is not mb aware (use the idioms substr($session,0,-32) to get the payload part of the string.
3. maybe substr doesn't cope with multibyte strings too, use explicitally  mb_substr (or whatever it is called).

To me the first case is the more probable. For what I can see.

Comment: ok, I used the wrong words, but it's from the CI framework,Why won't it work?

Comment: Added some other suggestion to the answer (too text for the comments)

Comment: thanks, to me the first one does not seem obvious.It receives the cookiedata as a serialized array and concats it with the md5 hash.
The next time the function is called, it reads the cookie and does the above. There is no tampering with the cookiedata inbetween.
It is very simpel, if I use a strongvalue for the cookiedata it evaluates ok. That would make it clear to me that it has something to do with the serializing.

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo:

```
md5($sessie.$this->encrypt_key))
```

should be

```
md5($session.$this->encrypt_key))
```

If you develop with notices turned on you'll catch this kind of thing much more easily.

You're not *encrypting* your data, you're *signing* it.

Answer (score 1):

> I was attempting to encrypt de cookie
>   data with md5, but I can not decrypt
>   it back for validation.

md5 isnt an encryption method. it creates a one-way hash that cant be turned back into the original data.

If you want to encrypt data try [mcrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php)

Comment: He uses MD5 only for message authentication.